# Is it possible to create a mongodb cluster using multiple MongoLab free account?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mlab

I was wondering if it was possible to aggregate multiple MongoLab (free) accounts to build a cluster.

It's maybe a weird question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, as replica set clusters are meant to share a single mongod. Feel free to contact us at support@mongolab.com if you need help!

-Chris@MongoLab